# tracing where the python libraries are imported from in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Is there anyway for Pycharm to trace where the python libraries are imported from in pycharm?  For example:

```
import abc from xyz

class efg(xxx):

  ...more codes
```

Is there any way to tell where xyz locates in the repo by using pycharm?  Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl + left click `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

As a user @[halfelf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958529/halfelf) mention, you can navigate by `Ctrl + Left Click` on `xyz` OR just left click on `xyz` and press `Ctrl + B` to go to *Decleration*.